System emergency stop error on Slamtec Apollo robot
We've been using an Apollo system from Slamtec for a project over the last six months.
This week, the robot started reporting a system emergency stop error.    We've rebooted the robot and the controlling computer.   We've made sure that the physical emergency stop button is not engaged and have engaged it/released it multiple times with no luck.
How can we troubleshoot the problem?

Is it possible to either physically disconnect it electrically or short it, depending whether it is normally open or normally closed during normal operation?

Excellent suggestion.   I have figured out that the switch is conducting when open and not when closed.     The emergency stop wire is sitting at 5 volts.    I am imagining that when it is not supposed to be in emergency stop mode, the system is reading 5 volts.   When the button is engaged, the reading would drop to 0.
I tried shorting the wire connection with the switch removed with no change in behavior.   I don't know if anything else in the system can trigger that error.

Logically speaking an emergency stop should just break the circuit (i.e. cut the power) when it is hit, so it should be closed during normal operating. However, that might not be guaranteed. Do you have, or maybe you can find, a schematic? That would help you to find an answer.
